# Issues adding WebDriverWait in a for loop - selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code, which runs well:

```
titles = results.find_elements_by_class_name("docsum-title")
    for title in titles:
        print(title.text)
```

It prints out a list of titles from the `find_elements_by_class_name`. The title's are also hrefs which I want to click to.
However, once I add click functions on `title.text` hyperlinks that go to a new page, (code below)

```
titles = results.find_elements_by_class_name("docsum-title")
    for title in titles:
        print(title.text)
        title_wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "docsum-title")))
        element = driver.find_element_by_link_text(title.text)
        element.click()
        print('clicked')
        abstract = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"abstract")))
        print(abstract.text)
        driver.back()
```

it only runs for the first iteration of the for loop - I'll the abstract.text the first time, but then it throws the error

```
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

at `print(title.text)`. I thought having the `title_wait` will make the code wait until the new page loads after `driver.back()` returns to the original page, but I guess I'm wrong.
Would appreciate any help!

For reference, the original link is https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=obatala%5BAffiliation%5D&sort=, and the page it clicks to is the [Bone Marrow Adipocyte paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29667012/).

Comment: Whenever you click() and leave the page the elements are now stale.

Comment: I suggest getting the number of elements to loop and then using xpath to retrieve the element you need.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this but I don't know the xpath to your element.It should be able to go back and forth finding the next class of docsum-title.

```
titles = len(results.find_elements_by_class_name("docsum-title")) 
for title in range(1,titles):
    title_wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"[class='docsum-title'][" + str(title) + "]")))
    print(title_wait.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are facing the stale element error while performing browser navigation, use below approach.

```
titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("docsum-title")

for i in range(len(titles)):
    titlesTemp = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("docsum-title")
    print(titlesTemp.__getitem__(i).text)
    title_wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "docsum-title")))
    element = driver.find_element_by_link_text(titlesTemp.__getitem__(i).text)
    element.click()
    print('clicked')
    abstract = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"abstract")))
    print(abstract.text)
    driver.back()
```