# How to avoid StaleElementReferenceException when using ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriverwait

I am trying to validate the attribute "innerText" of an element is updated (eg, from 100 to 50). To avoid using sleeps I am waiting for the attributeToBe. But I am receiving StaleElementReferenceException exception. Probably, because the DOM is reloaded. mportant note: The element is visible, present and without this the element.getText() returns the old value. So the test fails (because the attribute has the old value).

For now, I am ignoring the exception but would you suggest a better solution, please?

```
public void waitAttributeToBe(WebElement webElement, String text) {
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(webElement,"innerText", text));
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Exception:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Comment: Can you please fetch the element after the dom reload and then try this condition?

Comment: I hope this answer can help you [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63913905/10911205)

Comment: Could you paste entire script ?

Comment: @vishalgada do you mean re-instantiate the webelement? I am using Page factory the element is declared in the Page class.

Comment: @Maria Can you please try using the below code to instantiate the pagefactory
PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, TimeoutValue), this);

Comment: Hey, thank you all. I posted the answer how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone needs help on that, I fixed it by using the element locator instead of passing the webelement in the parameter. This was the why I was having the StaleElementReferenceException since the element was getting refreshed and I was accessing the old one.

```
public void waitAttributeToBe(By by, String attribute, String text) {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(by, attribute, text));
    }
```